# IOS/Storyboard/Autolayout: Make Textview Expand Vertically to Accomodate Text

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have been going through apple's documentation and answers on SO and can't get my UITextView within a UIScrollView to expand vertically dynamically as text increases.  Apple seems to say just set a low content hugging priority and that should be all you need.  But not working for me.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

I have pinned UITextview left and right and top.  I also have a view below it pinned to its bottom.  There is no height constraint.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.  The textview I am trying to make behave in this way is BlockView.  It is pinned above to contact image and below to notesview.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the text view's `scrollEnabled` property to false. By default it is enabled, which renders your text view with the height set in XIB (even if it doesn't have any height constraint).

Comment: Thanks.   That with changing the priority of the content view bottom to lowermost element bottom to 250 (so it will absorb changes in size) made it work.